# Can I control path miters in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, pen-tool

I am trying to draw some hair. But the shape layer acts weird in photoshop. Why does it become so pointy?

How can I make it look natural Like I can adjust the limit in AI, is there any way I can do that in PS?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I'm seriously wondering why you are insisting to use Photoshop for work where Illustrator is the far superior tool. This is not the first of your questions I see that indicate you have Illustrator experience, but you are running into Photoshop's limits where vector work is concerned. You *do* realise you can place Illustrator objects into Photoshop as a Smart Object, do you?

Comment: I just wanna learn :'(

Comment: I wanna know why photoshop doing that. I am as curious as a cat.

Comment: But thank you for pointing that out. I could have done that in AI and then paste it into PS. thank you.

Comment: I would ask that you please use specific and *descriptive* question titles. It's about allowing others to find your question in the hopes it helps them... random three word titles aren't very helpful.

Comment: @Scott Okay. FACEPALM

Comment: I understand you want to learn. A crucial part of learning is knowing when a tool is unfit for the job, especially when you have a way better tool at your disposal *and* know how to use it. It's like you want to build a house and insist on using just a chisel. Or using Excel to paint: https://mymodernmet.com/tatsuo-horiuchi-excel-spreadsheet-paintings/

Comment: hahahah, I learn my lesson today. Thank you @Vincent

Comment: you shouldnt look as illustrator and photoshop as alternatives to eachother. They are not, if you intend to use PS then you should approach it like painting. think of it thisway, illustrator is like scissors, glue and colored paper. While photoshop is an airbrush or oil paint. Sure you could airbrush solid shapes but why limit yourself.

Comment: @joojaa Oh my god! So beautifully you said! Like literature. I love it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop has no specific path miter controls in terms of custom values like in Illustrator.

You can control joints to a degree via the Shape Options in the control bar....

[image]

Beyond this, there's nothing in Photoshop to alter miter values which I'm aware of. But I am using a legacy version and not the latest release.

Most would be using Illustrator if they have experience with Illustrator for reasons such as this. The more control you want over path appearances, the more Illustrator becomes the preferred tool.

What is or is not "natural" is subjective and relative.